# How add a JScroPane to JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I want put in a JScrollPane a JTextField, is it possibile? this is my code:

```
    JTextField access;

 JPanel riga4 = new JPanel();

        JLabel label4=new JLabel("access");
        riga4.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 30, 10));
        riga4.add(label4);
        label4.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 62));
        //riga4.add(label4);

        access= new JTextField(15);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(access);       
        riga4.add(scrollPane);
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You probably want a [`JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) or [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

Comment: The right component which support multiple lines is `JTextArea`. See [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

Comment: What is the problem? There is no text in the text field so you won't see scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JTextArea instead of JTextField